# how to create a custom task form using aspx

Tags: task-list

How can i create a custom edit form for a task using aspx?
All the examples i see seem to use infopath.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean workflow task, see [Robert Shelton's](http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/10/05/free-sharepoint-document-workflow-workshop---part-4-on-workflow.aspx)
wonderful tutorial series. On this site you can find some marvellous videos too in that theme.

Comment: thanks but do these apply to sharepoint 2010? i see mostly stuff on 2007 here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Data View Web Part to create custom forms using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Sharepoint 2010, then the forms are basically InfoPath forms so they can easily be modified in InfoPath.  In Sharepoint 2007, you would want to hide the stock form on your ASPX page and insert a Custon List Form on the page.

Comment: thanks..must i have anything additional installed on my farm to edit these infopath forms? my client doesnt want to make any other investment apart from sharepoint..they dont want to buy infopath..isnt their an option to use aspx to create custom edit task forms in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: You'd need the Professional version of Office 2010 to get InfoPath so the forms could be edited.  Nothing else to install farmwise.  If they don't want to pay for the professional version of Office 2010, then they'll have to use Sharepoint Designer, DVWPs, and aspx pages,

Answer (score 0):

A good blog post on building aspx task forms for SP2010 (useful if you only have SPF) here - http://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1-of-2/